# Compiling with Listable option and Parallelization

Tags: parallelization, compile

I have a bunch of triangles (200k) I need to calculate the normals of. Here are five of them below, each one with its vertices in CCW order.

```
tris = {{{99.1175,-156.51,158.},{-63.7411,-173.073,158.},{-62.,-173.,158.}},{{-62.,-173.,3.},{-62.,-173.,158.},{-63.7411,-173.073,158.}},{{62.,-173.,158.},{99.1175,-156.51,158.},{-62.,-173.,158.}},{{-62.,-173.,3.},{62.,-173.,158.},{-62.,-173.,158.}},{{-99.1175,-156.51,158.},{-65.4575,-173.287,158.},{-63.7411,-173.073,158.}}};
```

Their normals can be simply calculated with

```
Normalize@Cross[#[[2]] - #[[1]], #[[3]] - #[[1]]] & /@ tris;
```

I'd like to Compile such function, therefore I reworked everything in the form

```
func=Compile[
{ax,ay,az,bx,by,bz,cx,cy,cz},
{
(-az*by+ay*bz+az*cy-bz*cy-ay*cz+by*cz)/Sqrt[Abs[-ay*bx+ax*by+ay*cx-by*cx-ax*cy+bx*cy]^2+Abs[az*bx-ax*bz-az*cx+bz*cx+ax*cz-bx*cz]^2+Abs[-az*by+ay*bz+az*cy-bz*cy-ay*cz+by*cz]^2],
(az*bx-ax*bz-az*cx+bz*cx+ax*cz-bx*cz)/Sqrt[Abs[-ay*bx+ax*by+ay*cx-by*cx-ax*cy+bx*cy]^2+Abs[az*bx-ax*bz-az*cx+bz*cx+ax*cz-bx*cz]^2+Abs[-az*by+ay*bz+az*cy-bz*cy-ay*cz+by*cz]^2],
(-ay*bx+ax*by+ay*cx-by*cx-ax*cy+bx*cy)/Sqrt[Abs[-ay*bx+ax*by+ay*cx-by*cx-ax*cy+bx*cy]^2+Abs[az*bx-ax*bz-az*cx+bz*cx+ax*cz-bx*cz]^2+Abs[-az*by+ay*bz+az*cy-bz*cy-ay*cz+by*cz]^2]
}
];
```

and run

```
func[Sequence @@ Flatten @ #] & /@ tris;
```

The speed gain is considerable (9.9 vs 1.2 seconds!), but I'd like to go further, namely using the Listable property and the Parallelization option. How can I do that? If I understand correctly parallelizability is a consequence of listability, so I added `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True` at the end of `func`. But, how should I call the function then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy: Make the input a matrix (array of rank 2); then the compiled function can thread directly over the input. No need for `Map` anymore. Also, you can use *Mathematica* to generate the symbolic code automatically from your function.

```
f = Normalize@Cross[#[[2]] - #[[1]], #[[3]] - #[[1]]] &;
Block[{X, XX}, 
XX = Table[Compile`GetElement[X, i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
cf = With[{code = f@XX},
  Compile[{{X, _Real, 2}},
    code,
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
 ]
```

Now, on my Haswell Quad Core:

```
tris = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100000, 3, 3}];
r1 = f /@ tris; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r2 = cf[tris]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[r1 - r2]]
```

> 3.18289
>
> 0.006599
>
> 2.39808*10^-14

The undocumented `` Compile`GetElement `` is a read-only instruction that---in combination with `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`--- does not perform bound checks. So make sure to call this functions with matrices at least of size $3 \times 3$; otherwise, the library tries to read memory that it is not allowed to read and the operating system kills the process (together the *Mathematica* kernel as its parent). So when you write a program that is supposed to be used by other people, always write a *Mathematica* wrapper that performs all the checks before calling the  `CompiledFunction`.

Comment: Thank you for showcasing `Compile``GetElement` as well. Can you please explain why I need to use two localisation constructs to create `code` instead of writing directly `f@Table[Compile``GetElement[X, i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]`?

Comment: You're welcome. The `Block` shields `X` and `XX` from potential global definitions and the `With` is a trick to enforce that the symbolic expression is evaluated and supplied in verbatim to `Compile`. One could also try `Compile[{...}, Evaluate[f@XX],...]`, but that is not very robust.